# Проблемы с компоновкой виджетов в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qlayout

Есть `QTreeView`, который должен прижиматься к левому краю и занимать фиксированный размер. 
И создаваемые `QTextBrowser`, которые располагаются справа от него, занимая всё остальное место.

Однако после их удаления, при создании новых между ними и древом остаётся пустое место, то есть они не занимают положенное им место.

Я всё ещё немного плыву в системе компоновки Qt, так что не могу понять откуда берётся эта пустота.

Важный момент: текст в этих браузерах может изменяться и сохраняться в файлы, и чтобы это корректно работало он должен быть именно `textbrowser` а не `selfl.textbrowser`.

Минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTreeView, QTextBrowser, QPushButton


class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.treebox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.treebox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)

        treeModel = QStandardItemModel()
        rootNode = treeModel.invisibleRootItem()

        testrow = QStandardItem('123')
        rootNode.appendRow(testrow)

        self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.text_manager)

        self.treeView.setModel(treeModel)
        self.treeView.expandAll()

        self.box.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.treebox.addLayout(self.box)

        self.setLayout(self.treebox)

    def text_manager(self, val):
        self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(val)
        textbrowser = QTextBrowser()
        closebtn = QPushButton('x')
        tblayout = QVBoxLayout()
        tblayout.addWidget(closebtn)
        tblayout.addWidget(textbrowser)
        self.treebox.addLayout(tblayout)

        def close_tb():
            self.box.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            self.treebox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            closebtn.deleteLater()
            textbrowser.deleteLater()

        closebtn.clicked.connect(close_tb)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот проблемы(пустое место между виджетами):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я немного упорядочил ваш код, чтобы он работал так как вы хотите.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QTreeView, QTextBrowser, QPushButton


class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        treeModel = QStandardItemModel()
        rootNode = treeModel.invisibleRootItem()
        testrow = QStandardItem('123')
        rootNode.appendRow(testrow)

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.text_manager)
        self.treeView.setModel(treeModel)
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        
        self.treebox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.treebox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.treebox.addWidget(self.treeView, 0)

    def text_manager(self, val):
        self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(val)
        
        widget = QWidget()                                               # +++
        
        textbrowser = QTextBrowser()
        closebtn = QPushButton('x')
        closebtn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, w=widget : self.close_tb(w)) # +++

        tblayout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        tblayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        tblayout.addWidget(closebtn)
        tblayout.addWidget(textbrowser)
        self.treebox.addWidget(widget, 1)

    def close_tb(self, w):                                                # +++
        w.deleteLater()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.resize(600, 600)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что делает второй аргумент в методе `addWidget`?

Comment: @type49  коэффициентом растяжения https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget